# Trying to SUM values from UNION with one column

Tags: sql, sum, union

I have a simple database with information about games and scores which looks something like this:

```
Tournament Black_ID    White_ID    Black_Score    White_Score
47          81          54          1              1
-------------------------------------------------------------
47          81          65          1              1
-------------------------------------------------------------
47          54          81          2              0
-------------------------------------------------------------
47          44          81          0              2
-------------------------------------------------------------
..
-------------------------------------------------------------
...
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

If a player wins they get 2 points, tie means 1 point for each and loss means 0 points.

I am trying to get a sum of all the points received by player 81 in tournament 47.

I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT SUM(Score) FROM(
    SELECT White_Score as Score FROM Table
    WHERE Tournament = 47 AND White_ID = 81
    UNION ALL
    Select Black_Score FROM Table
    WHERE Tournament = 47 AND Black_ID = 81
)
```

But it's giving me syntax error near '(end of line)' on the last line.

If I remove the `SUM(Score)` part like this:

```
SELECT White_Score as Score FROM Table
WHERE Tournament = 47 AND White_ID = 81
UNION ALL
Select Black_Score FROM Table
WHERE Tournament = 47 AND Black_ID = 81
```

It gives me a table like this:

```
Score
-----
1
-----
1
-----
0
-----
2
-----
```

I can't seem to find a solution on how to sum it up.

Answer (score 0):

You should add alias:

```
SELECT SUM(Score) FROM(
SELECT White_Score as Score FROM Table
WHERE Tournament = 47 AND White_ID = 81
UNION ALL
Select Black_Score FROM Table
WHERE Tournament = 47 AND Black_ID = 81
) sub  --here
```

Comment: Using `COALESCE()` inside `SUM()` is redundant, isn't it? `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values by default.

Comment: @RacilHilan I wanted to avoid `NULL` + 10 for example, when you will get NULL in result.

Comment: I don't follow, `SUM()` ignores (i.e. skips) `NULL` values, so you will never get `NULL` + 10. Anyway, your second solution is incorrect. It will give you the sum of all white and black if the player is 81 in either one. I think the OP wants the sum of only black when player is 81 in black, and only white when player is 81 in white. For the sample data in question, your query will return 8 instead of the correct sum of 4.

Comment: @RacilHilan `"I don't follow, SUM() ignores (i.e. skips) NULL values, so you will never get NULL + 10"` Example [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ec0d276b0335a2b88e31569fb9030b76) Never mind I will remove that part (the point was simple whenever you have to add values from 2 agg function it's safe to handle NULL)

Comment: An alias for the subquery might be useful but it is not necessary.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean you're trying to avoid `NULL` as the end result of the entire `SUM()`. OK, in that case, you should put `COALESCE()` outside `SUM()`, not inside it. That will be much more efficient to check one value returned by `SUM()` instead of each value that goes into `SUM()`. So `COALESCE(SUM(White_Score), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(Black_Score), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `UNION` and subqueries for that simple case. You can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN White_ID = 81 THEN White_Score END)
     + SUM(CASE WHEN Black_ID = 81 THEN Black_Score END) AS Score
FROM Table
WHERE Tournament = 47
```